# Using Google Analytics in a swift framework

Tags: google-analytics, swift2

I am trying to use GoogleAnalylitics in a swift framework. As per the documentation, I have added 'Google/Analytics' to my podfile, done 'pod install' and am now stuck because I can't create a bridging-header in a swift framework *(error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported)*.

Though `import Google.Analytics` is recognized, I get `Use of unresolved identifier` error with `GAI` and `GAIDictionary`. `GAITracker` gives `use of undeclared type error`. Any suggestions on what needs to be done?

It happens in my app-delegate -

```
public func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
 GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError);
 let gai = GAI.sharedInstance();
 gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose;
 ...
}
```

`GGLContext` is recognized but `GAI` and GAILogLevel give `Use of unresolved identifier`

Comment: Can you share your code snippet like where you added analytics code and which part its failing ?

Comment: In my app-delegate,
  `public func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError);

    let gai = GAI.sharedInstance();

    gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose;

...}`
GGLContext is recognized but GAI and GAILogLevel give `Use of unresolved identifier`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to downgrade from Goole's pod version 3.0.3 to 2.0.4 to make it work. Looks like there is something odd in podspec 3.0.3. Hope someone from Google looks at this and fixes it.